# Magento Category Navigation - Customising Topmenu.php, adding columns using "$colBrakes" + "shouldAddNewColumn"?

Tags: magento2, theme, navigation, topmenu, core

I am successfully customising the magento 2 navigation by extending 'vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php' (and also 'vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml', and .less). *(was not easy..!)*

I cannot find ANY INFO AT ALL on the web or in the source code about how to use the column functionality that is there.

There is this:

```
private function shouldAddNewColumn(array $colBrakes, int $counter): bool
{
    return count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake'];
}
```

and this:

```
if ($this->shouldAddNewColumn($colBrakes, $counter)) {
    $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
}
```

A little  confusing. The only other place it is in the source code is 'vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php' but that is not helpful either. Why can I not find any mention of it on the whole internet?

**So my question is, what should the $colBrakes array be like if I want columns added..???**

Thank You!

Comment: Couldn't get this to work so currently just using css columns (which have some issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939581/dynamic-css-multi-column-layout-update-columns-force-reflow)